# Change the shape of the curly braces of the newtxmath package

Tags: fonts, symbols, mathpazo, newtxmath, mathptmx

The curly braces of the `newtxmath` package don't seem good.

- newtxmath package curly brace

  [image]
- Mathpazo curly brace

  [image]

So is there a way to make the curly braces look better without actually having to replace the `newtxmath` package?

Comment: “Look more good” is quite an ambiguous sentence.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what about the curly braces you object to? Is it their height, their weight (thickness of stroke), their distance to the neighboring symbol, or something else? By the way, did you mean to write 'mathptmx' instead of 'mathpazo'?  (The latter package provides Palatino-type rather than Times-like fonts.)

Comment: @Mico I am not talking about their weight. Emm how do i tell, the braces appear more curved in the "mathpazo" package whereas the braces appeared like a straight line in the newtxmath package.

Comment: @Mico No I dont want to compare them. I see that the curly brackets for newtxmath newpxmath aren't good as the other packages offer. Their is no "curl" in the curly brackets and they appear line a straight line. I want to rectify this

Comment: As the answer I've posted below shows, `mathptmx` and `mathpazo` basically provide the curly braces of `Computer Modern`. If you want to replicate this look -- albeit with much tighter spacing, which you may prefer anyway -- with the `newtxmath` or `newpxmath` packages, you should load them with the option `cmbraces`. However, if curliness of the curly braces if what you care about most strongly, you should *definitely* look into using the `mtpro2` package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want *really curly* curly braces and wish to use a Times-like math font -- as would seem to be the case because of your consideration of the `newtxmath` package -- you should look into using the [mtpro2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) font package. ("mtpro2" is short for "MathTime Professional II".) The full `mtpro2` package isn't free of charge. However, its "lite" subset, which is all you need to generate curly braces, is indeed free.

The following screenshots show the nested curly braces that are generated by various packages. All screenshots are at the same magnification.

- `mtpro2`:

[image]

- `mathptmx`:

[image]

- `newtxmath`:

[image]

- `newtxmath` with `cmbraces` option:

[image]

- For completeness, hare are the nested curly braces that are generated if *no font package* is loaded, i.e., if the basic `Computer Modern` math fonts are used:

[image]

Some comments:

- The curly braces produced by the `mathptmx` package are essentially those of the `Computer Modern` font family: Shape, height, and spacing of the braces are all the same. (The curly braces produced by the `mathpazo` package -- not shown separately -- are very similar in size and shape, but are spaced *even more widely* than those of `mathptmx`.)
- The spacing between the nested curly braces is *much tighter* (and, to my taste at least, better) with the `mtpro2` and `newtxmath` packages than it is with the `mathptmx`/`Computer Modern` approach.
- If you want the `Computer Modern`-style braces along with the `newtxmath` package, you should load it with the option `cmbraces`. This will give you `CM`-shaped braces but with tighter spacing (which is probably more desirable anyway).
- At any rate, if *curliness* is what you care about most, there's no question in my mind that you should employ the `mtpro2` package.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\Biggl\{ \biggl\{ \Bigl\{ \bigr\{ \{ 
 \cdot 
\} \bigr\} \Bigr\} \biggr\} \Biggr\} 
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks \usepackage[cmbraces]{newtxmath} really helped. :)